# Format DATETIME during laravel blade foreach loop to only show time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach, eloquent

Here is my loop. Prints multiple records along with date/time column

```
@foreach($tableData as $i)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{$i->name}}</th>
                <td>{{$i->duration}}</td>
                <td>{{$i->friendsAmount}}</td>
                <td>{{$i->time)}}</td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

This prints under the time column

```
2020-11-14 19:42:00
```

I only want it to display the time

```
19:42:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with [php-carbon](/questions/tagged/php-carbon) :

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($i->time)->format('H:i:s') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use php date_format function:

```
{{ date_format($i->time, 'h:i A') }}
{{ date_format($i->time, 'h:i:s') }}
```

if its a string:

```
{{ date_format(date_create($i->time), 'h:i A') }}
{{ date_format(date_create($i->time), 'h:i:s') }}
```